# Дженерики В чём отличие между <T> и <?>?

Tags: java, generics

В Java в теме обобщения есть обычный параметр, например

```
class A <T> {}
```

А можно сделать так:

```
class B <?> {}
```

То, я так понимаю знак '?' это тоже самое, что и написать

```
class C <Object> {}
```

И получается, что туда можно запихнуть всё, что является наследником класса Object, ну получается всё, так? А в обычный параметр  разве нельзя впихнуть тоже всё или есть отличия?

Comment: При подобном объявлении класса вы параметрезируете класс типом Т(class A<T>). Т. е. далее в теле класса вы используете тип T как тип переменной или тип аргумента метода(print(T t){println(T.toString());}). Соответственно при надлежащем инстанцировании объекта(A<String> a = new A<>();) вы убережете себя от ошибки использования переменной не того типа(print(new Object()); уже не прокатит)). В случае с В и С запись вряд ли имеет смысл поскольку Object как вы правильно заметили является Root для всех классов.